# How to check the reverse relationships in the following system

Tags: php, mysql, join, authentication, artificial-intelligence

I've two tables `users` and `userdata` and  I've created them using :

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id INT(6) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  password VARCHAR(255)
);
```

and `userdata` through this:

```
CREATE TABLE userdata
 (
  adder INT(6) NOT NULL,
  added INT(6) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT adder_user FOREIGN KEY (adder) REFERENCES users(id),
  CONSTRAINT added_user FOREIGN KEY (added) REFERENCES users(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (adder, added)
 );
```

I've kind of login system see this `index.php` page:(Here user is added by entering his id an password and session is being set for each user)

```
<?php 
  session_start();
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>
            login
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="review.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="id">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I've `review.php` where I've checked for the user authenticity(on a basic level)

```
  <?php 

   session_start();
   $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','stackoverflow');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    $query = "SELECT `name`,`id`,`password` from `users` where `id` = '$id' and `password` = '$password' ";
    $run = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run);

    if( ($id == $row['id']) && ($password == $row['password']) )
    {
        // start session with the id of the one who is logged in
        // this is the id of the user who is logged in
        $_SESSION['id']= $row['id'];
        header('location:save.php?id=$id'); 
    }


}


?>
```

This is `save.php`, here is the main issue, Let say Alice is logged into my system, and she visits the `save.php` page to add `Bob` to my system.
There is save button on this page when some logged in user in my system(`Alice`)  try to add another user(`Bob`) into my system (`userdata` table), at that point I want to check this-> 
    has `Bob` has already added `Alice` (when Bob was logged In)? if so, when Alice clicks on save, the name `Bob` should be inserted into `userdata` table and `Alice` and `Bob's` name should be written in red, displayed to the user(using select query), because they both are added by each other.
If `Alice` wants to add `Bob` but `Bob` has not added `Alice` before, then after clicking save by `Alice` the name `Bob` should be inserted into the `userdata` table, and should be displayed without any color because `Bob` has not yet added her.

How can I solve this problem of When a user adds a name, you must **check if they are added to the reverse and in that case to indicate it**. For example, if Alice adds Bob and Bob has Added Alice you must indicate it (with some symbol)?

```
 <?php 
    session_start();

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','stackoverflow');   
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $id   = $_SESSION['id'];
    $insert = "INSERT INTO `userdata` ('adder','added') values ('$id','$name')";  

    $query = "SELECT aer.name AS Adder, 'added', aed.name AS added
              FROM users aer
              INNER JOIN userdata ud ON aer.id = ud.adder
              INNER JOIN users aed ON aed.id = ud.added
              WHERE
            (
             SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM userdata uda
                    WHERE uda.adder = ud.added
                    AND uda.added = ud.adder
             ) >= 1";

    $run = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run))
   {
echo "<div class = 'text text-center' id = 'special'>".$row['Adder']."  Added  ".$row['added']."</div><br>";


  }

 }

 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>save</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head><body>

  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form action="save.php" method="POST">

                        <input type="text" name="name">
                        <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" class="btn btn-success">



                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

 </div>

  </body>
 </html>
```

`users` table

[image: users]

here is `userdata` table containing adder and added columns

```
adder    added
1         2
1         3
```

first row  `Alice` added `Bob`
second row `Alice`  added `John`
[image: userdata table]

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: **Warning:** Never store passwords in clear text! Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: thank you so much, I'll definitely used it, but now I'm just  using this for testing purposes , BTW how can I solve the problem I've mentioned, please have a look @MagnusEriksson

Comment: You should also look into: [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql). Two of your three queries should currently fail because of this.

Comment: I would also recommend using best practices even if it is for testing purposes. When you refactor your code, you would need to change your code and your queries a bit, which might result in adding new issues or even fix current ones. There's never a good reason for knowingly writing insecure code and to debug code that needs to be rewritten after...

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear as well. What do you mean by the users "adding" each other? Do you mean that users can connect to each other, like a friend list? Or do you mean that they actually add new users into the system?

Comment: true !!!  I agree, @MagnusEriksson

Comment: I've added some images of tables that would be clear image of what I want to say, please have a look at the post @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Adding by each other means, when the `userdata` table contains the rows something like this.  (first row) `1      2`        and      (second row) `2      1`  which means that Alice added Bob and Bob added Alice, i.e both are added by each other if that make sense ? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Please try to solve the problem , I'm facing it from last two days and nothing is happening good. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: This is not clear. Is the problem the simultaneous access--"transaction processing", "atomicity', "serializability" & "concurrency control"--or just restrictions on what the tables can be--constraints? Please clarify via post edits, not comments. PS Answering "is it this or is it that" by "true" is not clear. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you must have a unique user identifier in order to understand whether he was added or not (for example, email)

then (just for example not to use in real projects)

save.php:

```
"SELECT `id` from `users` where `email` = '$email'";
```

if user exists do this (Since a user can be created by an existing user, you already have his id (In `$_SESSION['id']` for example)):

```
"SELECT * from `userdata` where `edder` = '$id' AND `edded` = '$_SESSION['id']'";
```

if the record exists, it means that they are added to the reverse.